# Use getdate in procedure or trigger SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to know how to use `GETDATE()` in code to get it running and how to make trigger for specific content in a column.

This one I would like to check if column `SUPPLY_DATE` which is date type in table `SUPPLY` is the same as today's date. If yes then 'supply today', if not 'no supply today' I think I'm also missing some if true statement (>1/>0) but don't know how to use it for date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P2
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT * FROM SUPPLY WHERE SUPPLY_DATE = GETDATE())
    BEGIN 
        SELECT 'SUPPLY TODAY' AS SUPPLY
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'NO SUPPLY TODAY' AS SUPPLY
    END

    IF @@ERROR=0 SELECT 'OK' AS OK
END
```

For trigger I would like to have it as:

1. After insert check table and specific column
2. If I add something with different primary key but same name it would rollback

When I have this trigger it won't let me insert anything to table THINGS and I'm not sure how to tell it to check for specific column instead of whole table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T3
ON THINGS
AFTER INSERT
AS 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM THINGS)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('THERE IS A THING WITH THAT NAME',16,1);
END
```

Comment: It looks like you're using syntax from Microsoft SQL Server or some other brand of SQL database. But you have tagged the question [tag:mysql]. Can you please confirm what does `SELECT @@version;` report?

Comment: MySQL uses `curdate()` or `current_date`.

Comment: If you don't want to allow duplicate names, why not just use a unique constraint?

Comment: You have 2 completely different questions there, therefore you need to ask 2 separate questions.

Comment: The rules for [data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) show that when you compare a `datetime` from `GetDate()` to a `date` in `SUPPLY_DATE` the `date` value will be converted to a `datetime`. As Dale K has pointed out, they will only match at midnight. `IF (SELECT * FROM SUPPLY WHERE SUPPLY_DATE = GETDATE())` _might_ make sense if it was `if exists( ... )`. Similarly `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM THINGS)` causes a `rollback` if there are _any_ rows in `THINGS`. Odd that you never reference `inserted`.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question you will need to cast `getdate()` to a date, because otherwise it has a time component and will only be equal to a date datatype at midnight.

```
SELECT *
FROM SUPPLY
WHERE SUPPLY_DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
```

Also

```
IF @@ERROR=0 SELECT 'OK' AS OK
```

Is pretty unlikely to ever have an error. And do you realise you are returning 2 datasets to the client for 2 pieces of information? You might want to consider using an `output` parameter and a return value which is best practice anyway.

Note: Ask your second question as a new question.